# Wordpress not checking if file exists with file_exists

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack, import, wordpress-theming

I am trying to import a file in Wordpress, but either it works with the raw (local file in localhost) or the bundled file on the server after "webpacking" it and serving from /dist/.
I am trying to make a logic that checks whether the local file exists - if so, use it, otherwise get it from dist:

```
$file = file_exists('/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js')
    ? get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js'
    // : get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/linksCount.js';
    : get_template_directory_uri() . 'non-existent.js';
wp_register_script('links_count', $file, array(), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('links_count');
```

The commented line is what should work on the server, but if I do not comment it it works locally and runs the file from the local /dist/, so I can't see the difference.
There's no way to make it work... tried with `get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js'` and `'../../src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js'` (relative to the actual file).
I am stuck, probably making a dumb mistake but I would really appreciate some help. I am not very experienced in Wordpress or PHP and hope to learn a bit more, so, if there is a complete different approach to fix this, please show me and I refactor the whole thing.
(BTW): calling `wp_register_script` with `get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js'` works perfectly, so I think it's something about the `is_file` or `file_exists`that I can't grasp.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php You can't use a relative path

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_template_directory()` to get absolute path of current template.
Try this:

```
$file = file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js')
    ? get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/javascript/pages/linksCount.js'
    // : get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/linksCount.js';
    : get_template_directory_uri() . 'non-existent.js';
wp_register_script('links_count', $file, array(), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('links_count');
```

Comment: That worked fine; I've tried it before, but in the wrong way: extracting the variable `$path` and using it both in the test `ìf (file_exists($path))` and in the value attribution to `$file`, to use on the `wp_register_script`, but the logic is different on each case, so it did not work. Had to make a bunch of tests to figure that out.